# jack not recongized in a dell inspiron 13 5000 series

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, dell-inspiron, headphone-jack

I have a [Dell inspiron 13 5000 series](http://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/dell-inspiron-13-5000).

When I'm putting the music through the speakers, it is working fine.

However, when I'm putting headphones into the jack, the music keeps playing in the speaker and not in the headphones.

The word headphones `écouteurs` is displayed but it does not say much.

[image]

Same in the config console

[image]

As you can see, there is another pair of speakers but those ones are deactivated. It maybe due to that but my troubleshooting instinct tells me the issue lies somewhere else.

[image]

And last (see below), the drivers do not have any issues

[image]

Questions are :

1. Should I try to reinstall the drivers even though nothing is showing me the issue lies with the drivers?
2. Have you experienced something similar with that line of laptops? If it is the case, how did you solve the issue?

The OS is Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Does Windows detect anything being plugged in at all?  Usually a window will pop up asking about what you just connected.

Comment: Nothing actually @CheesusCrust

Comment: What kinda headphones are you plugging in?

Comment: Normal head phones @cheesus-crust

Comment: Check that your drivers are up to date on the [Dell Support site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-13-5368-2-in-1-laptop/drivers/advanced). Of special interest are Audio, Chipset and BIOS (very carefully).

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @AndyK! Could you post the solution?

Comment: hi @konradmb I need to do a small gif. It is very visual. I will do that tomorrow

Comment: Hi @konradmb, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is usually driver related.

I had that trouble once with a dell inspiron n5110 laptop I was fixing.
I suggest you update your drivers to the latest (see dell support website, and even similar laptops audio drivers).

Afterwards, try to see if there is an option (in Realtek HD audio settings) that makes the internal and the external speakers (sometimes called front jack) be seen as the "same device". 
If this option is unpicked, it may leads to make the drivers simply add another output device instead of replacing the default internal one.

You can try this one released on 03/20/17 : https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER04189067M/1/Realtek-High-Definition-Audio-Driver_CMW4W_WIN_6.0.1.8059_A04.EXE

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Harry MC and Neil, it was driver related.

I reinstalled my [drivers](https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03878907M/1/Audio_Driver_VR8Y0_WN32_6.0.1.7908_A03.EXE), had a new software called `Waves MaxxAudio Pro` installed and voilà.

See the video below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To check if it's software issue, try testing it on Linux.

For example you can create [Ubuntu bootable USB stick](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
Then boot it, connect your headphones and check if they are working.

If they work on Ubuntu, then it's a software problem. If they aren't, it could be hardware issue, or e.g. BIOS setting.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Realtek drivers and MaxxAudio installed, but disabled "Waves MaxxAudio Service Application" in Task Manager's Startup tab, this will break headphone switching. You need to enable startup and reboot (didn't test logging out and in).

[image: screenshot of taskmgr's Startup tab, showing MaxxAudio enabled]